# Is there a plugin that allows me to automatically unminify the Javascript included on a site?

Tags: javascript, firebug, minify

Is there a plugin, add-on, Greasemonkey script or something similar (at worst, an easy to use proxy?) that automatically **unminifies** the Javascript files included on a site?

I know about e.g. [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) but doing this externally doesn't allow me to set breakpoints in the unminified code, for example.

Typical use cases for me:

- Analysing and learning from complex web frontends.
- Debugging Greasemonkey scripts which interact with the existing code.

I'm primarily interested in a solution that works with Firebug, but if there's something for the dev tools of Chrome or Opera, I'd like to hear about it as well.

Comment: I dunno if it exists, but good idea :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216583/beautify-javascript-and-css-in-firebug/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In chrome 13+, there is 'pretty print'.

1. Right click 'inspect element'
2. Go to Script tab
3. Click the curly braces in the bottom right.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: And there is the "Auto Prettify Minified Sources" setting to turn that on by default: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33753040/895245

Answer (score 77):

Someone has made JSBeautifier into a Firebug plugin:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deminifier/

This has made my day today!

Comment: I WANT TO UPVOTE THIS A MILLION TIMES. **THANK YOU!** (And thanks to Tim Stone for mentioning this answer to me!)

Comment: Oh that is beautiful. And surprisingly fast, much faster than the Fiddler solution. Can't believe I haven't found that before.

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin is no longer maintained and does not work with Firefox 4.

Comment: Script has been updated to support 3.6-5.*

Comment: Chrome's pretty print is much better than this. After installing  press Ctrl+/ to show add-ons bar to enable/disable js deminification for a page.

Comment: For those who read that it doesn't work, it's working perfectly fine for me on Firefox 20.0.1

Comment: It isn't "integrated" into Firebug at all.

Comment: Sorry Robert, english is my first language. Corrected it to say precisely what everyone else already understood: that someone made a firebug plugin. Thanks for the downvote! Please, come again!

Answer (score 8):

[Venkman](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/216/) JavaScript debugger has a pretty-printer.

There is also an [extension](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/extensions.asp) for Fiddler proxy.

IE9 developer tools also have a "format javascript" option (see "F12 Developer Tools and Formatting Minified Script" [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/28/html5-using-the-whole-pc-sixth-ie9-platform-preview-available-for-developers.aspx))

Comment: Fiddler works nicely. A bit slow, but that's what you have to expect when you're trying to unminify and reformat a big webapp. Not my preferred solution (would like to see direct Firebug integration), but this works. Thanks!

Comment: The Fiddler extension was updated Oct 2011 with the comment "Approximately 300 times faster than the old version, and less likely to mangle poorly formatted script."

Answer (score 3):

FYI - the same functionality is available in IE9's F12 Developer Tools: With script tab open, select the hammer/wrench button on the button bar ("Configuration"), and select "Format JavaScript".

Answer (score 1):

If the script is only minified for whitespace, some of the solutions offered may work.  As you mention, JSBeautifier is a useful tool.

However, if the JavaScript you're looking at has been compressed with a tool such as [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) or [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), the variables are going to be shortened and harder to understand.

To see this in action, compare the minified and unminified versions of jQuery (minified version uses Closure Compiler).

- original: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js
- minified: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js

For the goal of learning JavaScript, I recommend learning from libraries and plugins written by some of the best JavaScript developers out there.  Look at the source code for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Moo Tools](http://mootools.net/).  Look at code on GitHub by people like [John Resig](https://github.com/jeresig) or [Thomas Fuchs](https://github.com/madrobby).  Read [DailyJs](http://dailyjs.com/) and look at his examples.

I hope some of these tools help you in the process of learning.  These are the resources that have helped me most.

Comment: I don't care about a loss of variable names in this case, as long as I can set breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Webkit/Chromium can now do this as well, see [Webkit Bug 57942](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57942), [Changeset 83713](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/83713) and [Peter Beverloo's change summary post mentioning this](http://peter.sh/2011/04/web-audio-api-script-de-obfuscation-an-updated-ui-and-the-contentsettings-api/).

Don't ask me starting with which version of Chromium/Chrome this is available, but feel free to mention here if you do know. :)

Answer (score 1):

**"Auto Prettify Minified Sources" setting** of Firefox Firefox Developer Tools turns the [Prettify Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7466333/895245) feature on by default.

To enable it:

- open Firefox Developer Tools (Ctrl + Shift + I)
- Debugger tab
- engine icon on top right of the Debugger tab, *not* the global settings engine

[image]

This is documented at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Pretty-print_a_minified_file

Tested on Firefox 42.

Comment: Makes no sense why pretty print is available for their Debugger, but not for their Style Editor

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible with current tools. Show eval scripts is the most you can get.
Jsbeautifier.org is nice **open** thing, and someone can integrate it info firebug.

Answer (score 0):

PrettyPrint is a nice chrome extension for this, it automatically unminifies js in a heartbeat while using regular (Ctrl-U) source.

You can get it here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prettyprint/nipdlgebaanapcphbcidpmmmkcecpkhg/