# Human readable javascripts in chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

does anybody know whether Chrome Developer Tools can format javascripts into human readable form ? Some kind of beautifier would be handy. Let say that I'm using some JS library and I need to instantiate its object, so that I should know what to put into constructor. But searching through this huge library that has 4 lines in the Chrome Developer Tools user interface is quite annoying...

Otherwise the server side needs to take care of implementing "dev mode" that supplies javascript files that are not minified ...

Comment: pretty sure thats not possible, but I hope that I'm wrong because it would be a nice feature.

Comment: I did, but absence of this feature is quite surprising, so I better asked here

Comment: Firebug version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279319/is-there-a-plugin-that-allows-me-to-automatically-unminify-the-javascript-includ

Answer (score 424, accepted):

Some browsers have a *Pretty print* button that looks like this `{}` and it appears for HTML, JS, and/or CSS depending on the browser.

Chrome has it in the in the **Sources** tab:

[image: Chrome 40 pretty print button]

Firefox has it in the in the **Debugger** tab

[image: Firefox 35 prettify source button]:

*The position of these buttons may change, but it should always be in there*

Comment: On Windows it's a small icon that resembles -> { }. Caption says Pretty Print.

Comment: @with Thanks for mentioning that. I wonder why they implemented it differently on Windows/Mac OS.

Comment: does anyone know what happened to this Chrome feature? I think I've seen that in the past in my Chrome, but now it seems gone.

Comment: @superjos They've changed it to be the same on Mac OS and Windows now.

Comment: uhm, but I'm not even able to see that in context menu. Only the 'inspect item' command is there. See [screenshot](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/1558/googlegooglechrome.png).

Comment: @superjos Hmm, weird. You seem to have quite a few items missing. And when I click on empty space in the code view I only get "Save as...".

Comment: Still no dice for me when I try to prettify [this javascript](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/africa.js).  [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/nGDxCa3.png)

Comment: OMG **THAT** is a button

Answer (score 3):

There is the http://jsbeautifier.org/ for online usage (*you need to copy/paste*).

On that site they have a link to [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (*a web debugging proxy*) and a [JavaScript Formatter](http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/extensions.asp) for it (*3rd extention*).