# How to uncheck a group of checkboxes when another checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web, checkbox

I've created a search function on a website I'm developing but I'm stuck on this part. The search function has a list of categories which the user can check or uncheck in order to filter through the items. The options are almost identical to the way [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/courses) has implemented their search function. I would like to have all the other checkboxes unchecked when the **All Categories** option is checked and have the **All Categories** checkbox unchecked when anything else is unchecked. That sounds a bit confusing but it's exactly what that website has implemented.

Here's an example of the code:

```
<div class="filter-grade">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="grade-all" name="grade[]" value="0" checked><b>All Grades</b>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="grade-9" name="grade[]" value="9">Grade 9
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="grade-10" name="grade[]" value="10">Grade 10
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="grade-11" name="grade[]" value="11">Grade 11
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="grade-12" name="grade[]" value="12">Grade 12
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at their js files and figure out how they're doing it. You have a working example.

Comment: @ArrayKnight I tried that but their js files are all minimized and I tried going through each and searching for 'check' and 'checked' and other keywords but none showed up :/

Comment: Use js beautifier for minified js .Try this [link](http://bit.ly/17sB3iH) for more info . And debugger also offers js beautifiers. Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6318092/1426743) for chrome debugging tool reference.

Answer (score 3):

Despite my comment, I built out a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctnCn/5/

```
$('.group input').on('change', function() {
    var $inputs = $(this).siblings('input').add(this),
        $checked = $inputs.filter(':checked'),
        $all = $inputs.eq(0),
        index = $inputs.index(this);

    (index === 0 ? $checked : $all).removeAttr('checked');

    if(index === 0 || $checked.length === 0) {
        $all.attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Update to be project specific: http://jsfiddle.net/ctnCn/6/

```
$('.filter-grade input').on('change', function() {
    var $inputs = $(this).closest('div').find('input'),
```

Though I would like to point out that this is not the standard usage of the label element. I would suggest changing your markup to have labels and inputs be siblings (and use the "id" and "for" attributes to link them). Take a look at this reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp My previous fiddle also provides an example of the standard markup convention.

Comment: +1 Very nice. I would use .prop() though, instead of the attr.

Comment: It turns out using .prop() and .removeProp() introduces a bug, where .attr() and .removeAttr() do not. Where if you click "apple", click "all fruit", and then click "all fruit" again it would uncheck, despite being told to be checked.

Comment: Oh, I thought I saw some comparisons in there. You are right, no need to use .prop() there.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I tried it but something's not working and I'm not sure if it has to do with the structure of my checkboxes. I have a 'filter-subject' div with labels inside and the checkbox inputs inside each label. It would be great if you could help me out!

Comment: I would need to have a sample of your html to be able to tweak the fiddle to be specific to your project.

Comment: @ArrayKnight I updated my post with the code, thanks again for the help :)

Comment: I tried the code on my site and I know the Javascript is functioning since there are visible changes. However, the All Subjects option remains unchecked after the first time I uncheck it. In the Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that the 'checked' attribute is being set to the input but it just doesn't appear checked. Otherwise, the code works great :)

Comment: And I know it's slightly odd but I was using the code from the Bootstrap library for layouts and that's how they wrote their example

Answer (score 2):

This code also doing the trick .Get in the right path from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217953/1426743) of ArraryKnigh. You can also check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdsahib/bSLTz/7/) :

```
$('.group :checkbox').filter("[class!='group-all']").on('change', function() {
     var parentDiv=$(this).parent();
    $('.group-all',parentDiv ).attr('checked',false);
 });

$('.group :checkbox').filter("[class='group-all']").on('change', function() {
    var parentDiv=$(this).parent();
    $('input',parentDiv ).attr('checked',false);
    $(this).attr('checked',true);
 });
```

Comment: I had the same problem with your answer as with @ArrayKnight. My structuring is different than yours and I think it's causing an error even when I change the path :/

Comment: share your approach in a js fiddle. Its hard to assume what's going on there without having a look on that

Comment: @NartBarileva , updated my fiddle with your html structure. Try now ,it's working for me