# javascript shows no breakline in debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

When I upload to  dreamhost my page, I can't debug it because javascript appears with no end of line, like this for example:

```
function fun(){ alert("1");alert("3");if($("#tbTitulo").val()==""){alert("1");return;}}
```

so it is practically impossible to debug. I tried on firefox and chrome with the same results.  I don't know why this is happening. If you could give me some clue I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prettify the code in Chrome Developer Tools. The button is the last one on the bottom row on the sources tab (it looks like a pair of curly brackets):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6318092/1669279

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Beautify, unpack or deobfuscate JavaScript and HTML, make JSON/JSONP readable, etc.

check here 
http://jsbeautifier.org/

after that you can insert breakpoint to debug.

Comment: The browser does that already for you. *cough cough* install chrome