# Unable to locate the callback handler

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, handler

On a [website](https://appointments.uidai.gov.in/easearch.aspx) I'm trying to find out the part which is called when I select in the first select box in "State/UT" and which subsequently fills the "District/City" select box.

I'm using Firebug on Firefox and have turned on breakpoints in all the functions within the WebResource.axd file. I've also tried the *Break on Next* option in Firebug, but it takes me to some minified code in the ScriptResource.axd.

I want to catch the AJAX call's returned data in "District/City" so that I can take of VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION values to chain next call through POST submission using PHP.

**I'm unable to find the AJAX callback handler part. How to find it?**

The onchange handler for the selectbox has:

```
javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSate\',\'\')', 0)
```

But the script execution does not halt in this function when I set a breakpoint in it.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `__doPostBack`.

Comment: @Bergi I've already mentioned .. it does not stop in there when I select in  "State/UT" select box.

Comment: I too am having issues debugging sections of the code in Firefox and Chrome. Is your question about this issue specifically, or are you more-interested in learning something from the code?

Comment: Yes it'd be great to learn why I'm also not able to debug it. It does not seem to be working properly. So my question is about both.

Comment: This code is auto generated by asp.net ajax library, it is not very flexible for customization. But I am not sure why do you want to submit using php? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

The Chrome DevTools have a very useful way of stopping the script execution in this situation. Within the *Elements* panel you can right-click on any node and select *Break On...* within the context menu. It has several options, but for this case *Subtree modifications* is the right way to start (the AJAX response is an HTML snippet, so there is a great probability that JavaScript will change the webpage's DOM).

Here is stack trace:

[image: JavaScript call stack]

`f._onReadyStateChange` binds our AJAX's ready state event. It can be proven by its `_url` variable visible in debugger. I didn't explore what is happening there. Anyway, `e._updatePanel()` inserts HTML from the response into the DOM at line 1158:

> b.innerHTML = g

Note that this is the line number of the [formatted script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484407/human-readable-javascripts-in-chrome-developer-tools), while the actual script is minified.

Comment: Note that Firebug was the first tool to have those [Break on ... features](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Context_Menu) for DOM elements and it still has [a few more Break On ... features](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Break_On_...) than other devtools.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug's [*Net* panel has a *Break On XHR*](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel#Break_On_XHR) option, which helps you to locate where the request happens.

When that option is enabled, the script execution will break at the point where the XMLHttpRequest's `send()` function is called.

A few lines up (at line 4221) you will find the response handler function (called `_onReadyStateChange`) being assigned to the request's `onreadystatechange` property.

Search for the function definition in the code and set a breakpoint after the check for `.readyState === 4` (meaning the request has completed).

When you then select something from the drop-down list, your execution will halt at that point. Then you're able to see the response text within the [*Watch* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Watch_Side_Panel).