# Format JSP in Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, jsp, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to debug some JavaScript that is in a JSP file via Developer Tools. However the JSP is being displayed in the developer tools on a single line, making it very difficult to debug the JavaScript method I want. I have tried both Chrome and Firefox's develper tools. Is it possible, in either one of these browsers, to format files like this in such a way that they appear in the developer tools as they are in the IDE/text editor that you are working in? Failing that, is there a way that you can debug sections of a line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484407/human-readable-javascripts-in-chrome-developer-tools

Comment: In Firefox this does not work for non-JS files. In Chrome there is some limited formatting but after a few lines the formatting just seems to stop.