# Is it possible to beautify the javascript on a webpage for debugging purposes? (chrome or ff)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firebug

I'm curious how a particular page does something and want to find out how it works. However, all the JS is obfuscated and minified. Is there a way I can get the chrome debugger or firebug to beautify all the javascript to make stepping through the code more useful?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a plugin that allows me to automatically unminify the Javascript included on a site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279319/is-there-a-plugin-that-allows-me-to-automatically-unminify-the-javascript-includ)

Answer (score 1):

As of Chrome 12, you can right click in the Script pane and select "De-obfuscate source". [See screenshots and more info at Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/whats-new-in-google-chrome-12/)