# Expand inline JS into multiline using firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

There is an inline JS function inside an HTML page. Can firebug or some other tool expand the inline JS to multiline to make it easier for tracing the source?

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but you can copy and paste it into http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't have any impact on inline JavaScript, but for the sake of reference, the extension linked to [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279319/4823647#4823647) formats minified external files on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but [FireRainbow](http://firerainbow.binaryage.com/) does JS formatting in Firebug

Comment: A plugin for a plugin? Sweet.

Answer (score 1):

Two online options that I know of that would expand inline JS to multiline:
[JavaScript Beautifier](http://www.javascriptbeautifier.com/) and [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try copying and pasting into something that supports automatic formatting. Try pasting it @ http://jsbeautifier.org/.